# How to use DEPENDS in bitbake

Tags: build, dependencies, bitbake

I have a bitbake build environment with multiple recipes, which are dependent in a chain.

At the moment I have to do: `bitbake recipe1 && bitbake recipe2`

I have added: `DEPENDS = "recipe1"` to the meta-recipe2/recipe2.bb

`bitbake-layers show-cross-depends` shows this dependency.

There fore I expect running `bitbake recipe2` to build recipe1 first, however it does not.

What do I need to do to build the dependencies listend in the DEPENDS variable?

Comment: How have you confirmed that it's not working? Adding `DEPENDS = "recipe1"` in `recipe2.bb` should work (and has always done). Try running `bitbake recipe1 recipe2 -c cleansstate && bitbake recipe2`. Now you should see that `recipe1` is being built. I guess that in your tests, `recipe1` had already been built...

Comment: That would be nice but your assumptions are unfortunately incorrect. I definitely cleaned recipe1 before trying this. 

It is worth noting that these recipes are in different layers so:

meta-recipe1/recipe1.bb and meta-recipe2/recipe2.bb

I don't understand why this would make any difference though.

Comment: Please, retry anyway with the chained command I gave you. This has been working on all versions I've tried, which is basically everything since at laest 2010... If it still doesn't work, show us your recipes. Another thing to do, is to run `bitbake -e recipe2 | less` and look for the final value of `DEPENDS`.

Comment: I have done, well best I can. I don't have a cleanstate task in my recipes, only a clean.

I am unable to show you my recipes, hence using replacement names such as recipe1, recipe2.

Comment: It actually looks like I am doing the correct thing, which was mostly what I was asking.

I appreciate that if I am unwilling to share my recipes it will be hard to help. I don't have time to put together a dummy environment to demonstrate the problem right now, but will try and do so soon.

This is realistically just a nice to have feature in our build environment.

Comment: Well, you should have a `cleansstate` task in your recipe (automatically added). You could always show us the recipe with the name changed, even if we can't build it (though it's me ideal). Thus, please try the chained commands above. And add which version your using. And have you checked the final value of `DEOENDS`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding `recipe1` to `recipe2`by

```
DEPENDS += "recipe1"
```

should work fine for you. The line above means that before the `do_configure` task of `recipe2` can be run, the task `do_populate_sysroot` from `recipe1` will have to be completed. This should work for all versions of `bitbake` and `OpenEmbedded`.

You can achieve something similar to `DEPENDS += "recipe1"` by

```
do_configure[depends] += "recipe1:do_populate_sysroot"
```

If necessary, you could manually set up your own custom depends like this.

Comment: There's my problem... my recipe1 does not have a do_populate_sysroot

Comment: Try running `bitbake recipe1 -c listtasks` and check. If it lacks a `do_populate_sysroot` you need to add it. Otherwise, how is your `recipe2` supposed to use something from `recipe1`?

Comment: It is actually `do_configure[depends] += "recipe1:do_populate_sysroot"` but this got me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the custom dependencies are made by using depends, my fault. Internally, deptask is used for DEPENDS... Though, I'm still interested in how the second recipe uses the first, of your not installing into tube sysroot...

Comment: It's all custom recipes, written by my colleague. So a kernel is built output is copied to a kernel directory at root of bitbake environment level in do_install. The next recipe requires this to build. so do_check[depends] += "kernel:do_install" is what was required.

Comment: Sure, if it works for you... Though, in the end, I'd recommend installing to standard locations, DEPLOYDIR etc.

Answer (score 6):

The fact is that

```
DEPENDS += "recipe1"
```

Works nearly always but **not** always. Because it binds to do_configure that may be not called in the other image, like for example an initramfs image.

So for these cases better to bind to a task that is used, with

```
do_rootfs[depends] = "my-initramfs-image:do_image"
```